# Delete a row on a database (JSP)

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, jsp

i have this table  :

```
<table style="width:100%">
 <table id="Dest_table">
       <tr>
    <th>Check </th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>City</th> 
    <th>Url of Destination</th>
    <th>Category</th>
  </tr>
  <tr> <%while(rs.next()){ %>
    <td><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
    <td> <%=rs.getString("COUNTRY") %></td>
    <td> <%=rs.getString("CITY") %> </td> 
    <td> <a href=<%=rs.getString("URL") %> > <%=rs.getString("URL") %> </a>

  </td>
  </tr>
   <% } %>
</table>
```

and this function to delete a row on the table:

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
 function deleteRow(Dest_table) {
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById(Dest_table);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }


            }
            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }



    </SCRIPT>
```

but beyond the row that i am deleting in the function , i need the same row to delete it on the database , but i dont know how... any help?

Comment: get yourself to do some research !

Comment: You need to do it in Java, on the server, since that is where your database lives.

Comment: i search but didnt find sth usefull , the statement of delete  is : delete from ... where ... here i need to delete a row not a specific record...

Comment: Just delete that row from database because if you will delete from DataBase it will not display at view side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YOU CAN TRY THIS:**

Add a hidden input in your table. Then place the row id of the records of your database on it.

```
<tr> <%while(rs.next()){ %>

    <td><input type="hidden" value="row_id" id="rows"/></td>

    <!--insert your code here-->

</td>
```

Create a function for deleting row in database:

```
function delete(row_id) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", jsp_url?row_id, false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    document.getElementById("table_id").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

Where *jsp_url* is the url of your jsp and *row_id* is the id of the table row you want to delete. Then call the delete function in your loop for deleting the table row.

```
for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {

    <!--insert your code here-->

    var row_id = document.getElementById('rows'+i).value;
    if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {

        <!--insert your code here-->

        delete(row_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: on jsp url what jsp page will fill ? the current? and on row_id i dont know what the user will check , can u be more analytical , because i am new at this and i dont know many things.

Comment: Did you try this one? Your page should not redirect to the _JSP_ delete page. Just call the _JSP_ delete page then catch the row_id that will be passed by your current page and execute the code for deleting the record on your database. You said that you were able to delete the row on the table of your _JSP_ page, so you should also be able to get the row_id of the row that you were deleting.

Comment: can you write your full code (with mine too) in order not to do a mistake and also should i make a new page jsp delete page? (with database code, if yes what code should i have in it ? )

Comment: my jsp delete code i dont know if its right... `<%-- 
  
         
         
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
   String myDatabase = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project_app?user=root&password=1234"; 
   Connection myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(myDatabase);
   Statement myStatement = myConnection.createStatement();  
   
    
   myStatement.executeUpdate("DELETE  FROM DEST WHERE ID_DEST ='"+request.getParameter("id")+"'  ");`

Comment: and my database table that i want to delete row is `DEST(ID_DEST auto_increment , country,city,url , primary key (ID_DEST));`

Comment: Did you try to execute this? What happened?

Comment: Did the jsp_delete called?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        StudentDAO db = new StudentDAO();
        db.delete(id);
        response.sendRedirect("list");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

  
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


}
public void delete(int id) {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM [dbo].[Student]\n"
                + "      WHERE id = " + id;
        try {
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StudentDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your code? Seems like you've done it for Java and the OP wants it for javascript.